# CSS - efficiently using classes

Tags: html, css

I have written a class for a textfield with a certain style. The field appears at 2 very different place within the website, with different parent elements. The second need another margin-top. What is an efficient way to change the original margin-top, since I cannot use pseudo-classes?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57daw/)

HTML

```
<div class="some_parent">
  <div class="my_styled_field"></div>
</div>
 .....

<div class="some_other_parent">
  <div class="my_styled_field"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my_styled_field{
    margin-top: 2rem;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the most efficient way - most of the time - as in best performance, would be to add another class to your second styled_field.

If you add another class to your second styled_field, you would need only 1 reflow to reach it:

```
.newclass{margin-top:5px;}
```

Whereas using the descendant selector which others are selecting is surely worse performance, this means the browsers has to check a lot of elements recursively:

```
.parent .styled_field
```

If you don't want to add a class for some reason, better performance than the descendant selector would be the child selector:

```
.parent > .styled_field
```

When thinking about css performance, remember that even though we read left-to-right, browsers read right-to-left.

Where we would check all .container elements for an image-tag, browsers find all image-tags - then checks if they are in a .container

Answer (score 3):

```
.some_other_parent .my_styled_field{
margin-top:3em; //what ever you want
}
```

this is the way to apply some other styles to the same class, having different parents .

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS class hierarchy:

```
.some_other_parent .my_styled_field {
   margin-top: 2em; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Youc can do this:

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/57daw/1/)**

```
.some_parent .my_styled_field{
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color: red;
}
.some_other_parent .my_styled_field{
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    background-color: green;
}
```

This way, you aply style to `.my_styled_field` depending on his parent element.